# Error al conectar firebase con android

Tags: android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]tenia una app conectada a firebase pero ahora quiero agregarle mas cosas pero no me conecta y me sale este error Firebase: Connect to Firebase failed. Please check your internet connection and try again. If errors persist, you can connect manually at https://console.firebase.google.com  pero mi internet esta bien

Comment: ¿que correo estás usando para la cuenta de firebase?

Comment: estoy usando mi correo de gmail

Comment: es raro porque si funcionaba

Comment: y para esa cuenta cuantos proyectos de firebase has creado?

Comment: solo dos proyectos

Comment: usaste la herramienta de android studio para conectarte con tu firebase?

Comment: tmb ya lo pude arreglar tuve sacar y agregar de nuevo las dependencias